# How to keep form data filled even if I return to previous page?

Tags: angularjs

Let us suppose, I have a form which contains the multiple fields named as:

```
Name, Id ,Address and MobileNo.
```

After filling all details, User is moved to next page.

After that, if I press back button and move to the previous page then I want that data to be filled already which I filled last time.

How can I do it with Angular JS?

Comment: Is it **angular** or **angularjs**?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In angular 10+. I used a service, where the data sharing was done by BehaviorSubject<any>() for this purpose. Please make sure to subscribe & unsubscribe properly.

Answer (score 5):

You can preserve your form value in the **web storage** or using a **service**. What you have to do is get the form value on the **component destroy lifecycle hook** and send it to a service or store it in  webstorage.

Solution below is the simplest since Services live in memory and keeps alive among the context of the instance (for instance the APP or the Browser Tab you are in)

**Service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CacheService {

  private formData: any;

  constructor() { }

  public setFormData(formData: any): void {
    this.formData = formData;
  }

  public getFormData(): any {
    return this.formData;  
  }

}
```

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./styles.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private cacheService: CacheService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.patchValue(
      this.cacheService.getFormData();
    );
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.cacheService.setFormData(this.form.value);
  }
}
```